# How to get nearby marinas, docks and boat launch inside a map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I checked a list of all available types in Google Place Search API.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

Google is not providing **marinas, docks and boat launch** in place search. Is there any way to get these using the Google Place Search API?

Comment: I am also looking for same requirement but i have not found any solution still so if you get any solution please help me.

Comment: I've made a small edit to your question to show that you're trying to achieve this specifically using the `Google Place Search API.`, otherwise it seems like you're trying to find an api to achieve this and that's off-topic, feel free to revert if you want though :)

Answer (score 1):

Like you correctly said, these types are not currently supported through Google's Places API. However, I recommend you file a feature request for this in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309) so that Google Engineers may consider adding these types in the future.

Hope this helps!